# Autocomplete in Razor page in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I am looking for an autocomplete in an ASP.NET Core Razor page which dynamically loads text from the database based on my typing.

Comment: you can find tutorial on internet on how to implement https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `oninput` event combined with `ajax` to achieve your goal. Your can refer to my example below.

Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}
```

TestPage.cshtml.cs:

```
public class TestPageModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;
    public TestPageModel(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public TestModel Model { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
    }

    public JsonResult OnGetAskData(string name) 
    {
        Model = _context.TestModel.Where(c => c.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();

        return new JsonResult(Model);
    }
}
```

TestPage.cshtml:

```
<div>
    <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Model.Name)</label>
    <input id="Name" oninput="myFunction(this)"/>
</div>
<div>
    <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Model.Description)</label>
    <input id="Des" />
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        function myFunction(e)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "?handler=AskData&name=" + e.value,
                success: function (response) {
                    if(response != null){
                        $("#Des").val(response.description);
                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

Test Result:

[image]